# Unable to write to file, even with right write access

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, permissions, file-permissions

File permissions are `-rw-rw---a`, and here are the security permissions:

[image: permissions]

I am the user (name completely blacked out). Why do I still get this error:

[image: Access is denied]

Comment: You are saving to the root of the C volume. That is strongly discouraged (and has been for years). I have not windows 8 to test with but I would not be surprised if windows now enforces this.

Comment: Hennes & @big-chris : Yeah, I was only using `C:\foo.txt` because programmatically it's shorter than `path.join(os.tmpDir(), 'foo.txt')`. Just messing around in the Node.JS REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard user (even the **Administrator** account) can't create or write to files in the root `C:\` for security reasons. **They can only create folders.**

Your user account (incl. **Administrator**) runs with standard user privileges and Windows has been designed to prevent writing to the root `C:\`. Elevating your action by using the `Run as Administrator` will overrule this - giving you the desired ability to write any file you please - but if you break your system you accept full responsibility (by enabling the action through UAC) for the consequences.

As @Henned pointed out, why, in normal use, would you want to write a file to the root of your `C:\`? Normal files should be kept in your user profile. Program files should be stored, you guessed it, in `Program Files`. There is simply no need, anymore, to write to the root of `C:\`...